# How to change an arrayList once a app is deployed?

Tags: android

I would like to change the value of a ArrayList once a application is deployed. I want to be able to change it monthly.

I thought hosting a text document on my website.. Reading from it through the application and set the values to variables and set the variables to the ArrayList.

Would this be a good way to go about doing this?
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to update the app every month, I guess that would be a simple way of doing it. In your case, I would use a HTTP Post service. This [guide](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) and this one [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) might help you.

Comment: If i use httpget, i have no way of changing the URL. What would the request be reading?

Comment: I apologize, but could you rephrase what you're asking about?